# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tweepy'

Tags: python, pip, tweepy

I have been trying to make a Twitter Mining Bot and this is my code:

This is the code I wrote on Atom

```
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener_

from tweepy import OAuthHandler_

from tweepy import Stream_

import twitter_credentials

class StdOutListener(StreamListener):

def on_data(self, data):
    print(data)
    return True

def on_error(self, status):
    print(status)

if name == "__main__":

listener = StdOutListener()
auth = OAuthHandler(twitter_credentials.CONSUMER_KEY, twitter_credentials.CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(twitter_credentials.ACCESS_TOKEN, twitter_credentials.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)

stream = Stream(auth, listener)

stream.filter(track=['MDH'])
```

I used Atom and tried to run my code from the command line. But have been getting this error

```
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tweepy'
```

But, I have already imported tweepy. I checked that from pip list on the command line.

I also saved the python script with a different name and ensured that the python and pip versions were the same.
Can someone please point me in the right direction?

UPDATE: So, I tried re-installing and installing Tweepy. It didn't work. I also tried editing the environment path. What finally worked was instead of using Atom and Command Line, I used Pycharm.

Comment: Make sure you have ```Tweepy``` installed. Can be acheived by ```pip install tweepy```

Comment: If it is already installed refer to the answer by xl3ehindTim

Comment: When pip installing, use `python -m pip install <package>` which will use the same python you are using for your script. `pip` by itself could point to anything. To see, compare `pip -V` with `python -m pip -V`

Comment: Please refer this url http://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/install.html .

Answer (score 0):

Try to pip uninstall [tweepy](https://www.tweepy.org/) and install [tweepy](https://www.tweepy.org/) again.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know about [tweepy](https://www.tweepy.org/) but i always got this problem

Here is how to fix it:

1. Try to re-install [tweepy](https://www.tweepy.org/)
2. If you have 2 Python with different versions, try running code with version that have the [tweepy](https://www.tweepy.org/) module
3. Make sure you have [tweepy](https://www.tweepy.org/) module
4. Try reading the installation docs again, so you don't miss anything that needed to install

If you already try that but it still doesn't work, try discuss this with a professional programmer